# Serialize/Deserialize ODATA xml to C# object

Tags: c#, xml, odata, feed

I need to convert the ODATA XML to C# Object and back
Sample xml.

```
 <entry xml:base="abc.com:8000"
       xmlns=w3.org/2005/Atom"
       xmlns:m="schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"
       xmlns:d="schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"
    >
       <id>abc.com:8000</id>
       <title type="text">MaintNotifSet</title>
       <content type="application/xml">
          <m:properties>
             <d:NotifType>MA</d:NotifType>
             <d:Dscid>...dsc id...</d:Dscid>
          </m:properties>
       </content>
    </entry>
```

Are there any libraries exist to help the parsing. Please throw some light.

Answer (score 0):

Use XSD command tool inside visual studio installation

```
XSD MyXml.xml
```

this will generate MyXxl.XSD
then

```
XSD /c myxml.xsd
```

this will generate myxml.c which contains your classes

Comment: This is not plain xml. This is a dataservice response which has cusom xml tags like <m: properties>.  xsd doesnt work

Comment: what about this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/